# Laravel 5.4 validar dos campos único compuestos

Tags: php, laravel, validación

Hola Antes que nada un saludo de mi parte y la duda es la siguiente con respecto a validar los datos en Laravel cuando tienes 2 campos únicos compuestos, aquí comparto la migracion que hice:

```
Schema::create('personas', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->enum('tipo_identificacion',['N', 'E', 'P'])->comment('N-NACIONAL, E-EXTRANJERO, P-PASAPORTE');
            $table->string('numero_identificacion', 50)->comment('NUMERO IDENTIFICACION DE LA PERSONA');
            $table->string('nombre', 100)->comment('NOMBRE DE LA PERSONA');
            $table->string('apellido', 100)->comment('APELLIDO DE LA PERSONA');
            $table->enum('sexo',['M', 'F'])->nullable();
            $table->date('fecha_nacimiento')->nullable();            
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->unique(['tipo_identificacion', 'numero_identificacion'], 'indice_documento_identificacion');
});
```

Si se fijan bien tengo dos campos que son 'tipo_identificacion' y 'numero_identificacion', son campos que los estoy declarando como un indice único.

Ahora bien lo que necesito saber es, ¿Como hago para validar ya sea utilizando el Requests, para especificar que esos 2 campos no sean duplicados?

Comment: Anteriormente logre validar los datos con un campo unico, pero no se como hacerlo cuando tengo un indice de 2 campos.

Comment: ¿por qué no te sirve la validación de campo único en cada uno de ellos?

Comment: Saludos, ya lo hice pero no lo valida ya que es un campos compuesto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que ya encontre la solucion utilizando un request. En estos links me documente para ver como podria validarlo de una forma mas organizado

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36926337/check-for-composite-unique-index-input-via-request-in-laravel

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-validate-unique-combination

Yo hace días lo hice con un campo utilizando request, aquí comparto el código que hice para validar los datos, incluyendo el campo **cedula**, para que sea un campo único y también valida cuando va a actualizar, mas o menos es lo que yo he entendido para validar los datos.

**Validando con un campo unico**

```
public function rules() {



        $validar_update=$this->get('id_persona')>0 ?", ". $this->get('id_persona'):"";


        return [
            'nombre' => 'required|min:3|max:100'
            , 'apellido' => 'required|min:3|max:100'
            , 'cedula' => 'required|min:3|max:15|unique:personas,cedula'.$validar_update //validando campo unico
            , 'sexo' => 'required|in:M,F'
        ];
    }
```

**Validando un indice campo compuesto con 2 columnas**

```
public function rules() {
        $validar_update = $this->get('id_persona') > 0 ? $this->get('id_persona') : "NULL";







        return [


            'tipo_identificacion' => 'required|in:N,E,P'
            , 'numero_identificacion' => 'required|min:4|max:50'

            , 'numero_identificacion' => 'unique:personas,numero_identificacion,' . $validar_update . ',id,tipo_identificacion,' . $this->get('tipo_identificacion') //validando campo unico compuesto

            , 'nombre' => 'required|min:2|max:100'
            , 'apellido' => 'required|min:2|max:100'
            , 'sexo' => 'required|in:M,F'
            , 'fecha_nacimiento' => 'required|min:10|date'


        ];
    }
```

El detalle esta despues del 4to. parametro, por defecto son 3 parametros para especificar la validacion de un dato unico.

Primer parametro: se especifica la tabla para validar (personas).

Segundo parametro: se especifica la columna de la tabla para validar (numero_identificacion).

Tercer Parametro: se va a ignorar la fila de la tabla a comparar utilizando un valor para la clave primaria, es decir, el id primario. Generalmente se usa para cuando vas a modificar un registro.

Cuarto parametro: se especifica la columna que posea la clave primaria,  (id).

Quinto parametro: se selecciona una segunda columna para validar en la tabla, (tipo_identificacion).

Sexto parametro: se agrega el valor de la segunda columna a comparar.

```
'unique:personas,numero_identificacion,' . $this->get('id_persona') . ',id,tipo_identificacion,' . $this->get('tipo_identificacion')
```

Apartir del 4 parametro las busquedas se hacen mas explicitas.

Comparto esto para ver que les parece. 
Saludos.