# Validar campos unicos en laravel

Tags: laravel, validación

estoy comenzando con Laravel y requiero de un poco de ayuda para validar que tres campos sean únicos.

El Problema:

Tengo una Tabla con las siguientes columnas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
//Aquí  mi código de validación. 

 $request->validate([
           'sub_lote'=> [
              'required',
          'unique:sgsublotes,sub_lote,NULL,NULL,nombre_lote,'. $id_finca,        
                    ],
              'nombre_lote'=>[
                   'required',
          'unique:sgsublotes,nombre_lote,NULL,NULL,sub_lote,'. $request['sub_lote'],
                    ],
                ]);
```

La idea es que no exitan un nombre_Lote, sub_lote para el mismo id_finca. es decir que no se repitan

Esta validación tiene la particularidad que al crear el primer registro, por ejemplo:

Nombre_lote    |   Sub_lote     | id_finca
Becerro           Lote 1            1

Ya no me deja crear más registros, presumo porque ya el valor becerro existe y no me deja crear otro nombre de lote con el mismo valor.

La idea es que me permita crear los diferentes lotes, sublotes para cada id_finca, pero que no se repitan.

Espero haberme explicado, y que pueda ayudarme, Saludos.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Laravel 5.4 validar dos campos único compuestos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/102626/laravel-5-4-validar-dos-campos-%c3%banico-compuestos)

Comment: unique es un tipo de indice de la bd, tendrias que modificar el indice que sea compuesto